# sp_start_job only running 20 times concurrently - can I adjust?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, linked-server

I have a procedure that has a loop that calls sp_start_job to run a query against multiple linked servers.

Each run of the loop calls a job that queries a specific linked server. (An openquery that inserts the results into a table on the local server).

However when running the procedure and looking at sp_who2, it appears it's only running the procedure against 20 remote server at a time.

Where can I control how many servers it attempts to connect to at any give time? I'd like to tweak this to get maximum speed without over loading the server.

I have max worker threads set to 300 and max number of concurrent connections set to unlimited.

The procedure that runs:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RunStoreQuery]
  @name AS NVARCHAR(40)
AS
  DECLARE @row AS INT,
    @maxrow AS    INT,
    @store AS     NVARCHAR(8),
    @sj           NVARCHAR(40),
    @jobs         NVARCHAR(40)
  SELECT @maxrow = Max(row#)
  FROM   (
                  SELECT   row_number()OVER(ORDER BY try_cast(s.NAME as int) ASC) AS row#
                  FROM     sys.servers s
                  WHERE    LEFT(s.data_source,2) = '10') s
  SET @row =1
  WHILE @row <= @maxrow
  BEGIN
    SET @jobs = @name
    SET @store =
    (
           SELECT s.named
           FROM   (
                         SELECT named
                         FROM   (
                                         SELECT   row_number()OVER(ORDER BY try_cast(s.NAME as int) ASC) AS row#,
                                                  ('['+ s.NAME +']') AS                                     named,
                                                  try_cast(s.NAME AS int) AS                                intnum
                                         FROM     sys.servers s
                                         WHERE    LEFT(s.data_source,2) = '10') t
                         WHERE  t.row# = @row) s)
    SET @jobs= @jobs+@store
    SET @store=N''''+@store+N''''
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job
      @jobs
    SET @row = @row + 1
  END
```